# Elasticsearch MongoDB river import after date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

Is it possible, using elasticsearch and mongodb river, to import documents which are created after a specified date (documents includes a timestamp) ?

Comment: How about a [range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) on the `mongoindex`?

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, I have 10 millions documents per day in mongo, and a small ES which can't handle the whole data!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question was posted, but just in case someone else finds it useful. You can use a custom filter when creating the river, in the *mongodb* section of the request,

```
mongodb : {
    ...
    "filter": ${mongo.filter},
    ...
}
```

this way, the river will only index those documents that match the filter condition, however there is a limitation, according to the docs, the river won't remove the documents that at some point in the future stop matching the filter. See more info [here](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki/MongoDB-custom-filter).

A somewhat more complicated way to accomplish this is by using the *initial_timestamp* option, in which you provide a script (javascript) that defines the timestamp for the initial document import, see an example [here](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/commit/57fc1c7867a24211d2acd92ca7b50d5859ad2c27). It's all in the [project wiki](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki#fn9).